# React native, shoutem/ui : navigating back on NavigationBar does not work on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, navigationbar, shoutem

I am struggling to make back navigation arrow on shoutem/ui NavigationBar work on iOS. The navigation bar looks like this and works on Android as expected (tap on the arrow navigates to specific predefined view) :

[image: Navigation bar]

The related layout is as follows :

```
import {
  Text,
  Button,
  View,
  Image,
  Divider,
  Spinner,
  NavigationBar,
  Caption
} from '@shoutem/ui';


render() {
  const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
  if (this.state.submitted && this.props.loading) {
    return (
      <Spinner style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }} />
    );
  }
  return (
    <Container style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}>
      <Content>
          <NavigationBar
            styleName='no-border'
            hasHistory
            navigateBack={() => navigate('WelcomeScreen')}
        />
        <Grid>
          <Row style={{ height: 100, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', paddingTop: 100 }}>
            <Image
              style={{ width: 96, height: 89 }}
              source={require('../login-logo.png')}
              blurRadius={1} />
          </Row>              
          //some other rows and columns
        </Grid>
      </Content>
    </Container>
    );
   }
 }
```

On Android the following works as expected. On iOS (Xcode simulator) the  navbar is displayed correctly, however tapping on it does nothing. No log events nor errors are generated as well. I assume that the navbar can somehow be overlaid by some other element. However, the same problem exists with the other views with different elements inside the grid below the navbar. Does anyone have experience with this issue? What is the most likely cause and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try moving `NavigationBar ` outside of content and inside of `container`, I'll add my answer later.

Comment: Thank you for the input!! This did not work out though. What worked is replacing "no-border" style with inline. Will post an elaborate answer tonight so that the other users might benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The "no-border" styleName applied to NavigationBar turned out to be the offending code piece in this case. Replacement with "inline" worked around the issue while introducing a slightly distinguishable border below the NavigationBar. However, this looks like a bug and the following issue has been opened in shoutem/ui GitHub repository : https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/398